# Set console title in C++ using a string

Tags: c++, windows, console, java-native-interface, title

I would like to know how to change the console title in C++ using a string as the new parameter.
I know you can use the `SetConsoleTitle` function of the Win32 API but that does not take a string parameter.
I need this because I am doing a Java native interface project with console effects and commands.
I am using windows and it only has to be compatible with Windows.

Comment: `SetConsoleTitle` does accept a string

Comment: google first your problem, this is so simple to find...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [`SetConsoleTitle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686050%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function does *indeed* take a string argument. It's just that the *kind* of string depends on the use of UNICODE or not.

You have to use e.g. the `T` macro to make sure the literal string is of the correct format (wide character or single byte):

```
SetConsoleTitle(T("Some title"));
```

If you are using e.g. `std::string` things get a little more complicated, as you might have to convert between `std::string` and `std::wstring` depending on the `UNICODE` macro.

One way of not having to do that conversion is to always use only `std::string` if `UNICODE` is not defined, or only `std::wstring` if it is defined. This can be done by adding a `typedef` in the `"stdafx.h"` header file:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
typedef std::wstring tstring;
#else
typedef std::string tstring;
#endif
```

If your problem is that `SetConsoleTitle` doesn't take a `std::string` (or `std::wstring`) it's because it has to be compatible with C programs which doesn't have the string classes (or classes at all). In that case you use the [`c_str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) of the string classes to get a pointer to the string to be used with function that require old-style C strings:

```
tstring title = T("Some title");
SetConsoleTitle(title.c_str());
```

---

There's also another solution, and that is to use the explicit narrow-character "ASCII" version of the function, which have an `A` suffix:

```
SetConsoleTitleA("Some title");
```

There's of course also a wide-character variant, with a `W` suffix:

```
SetConsoleTitleW(L"Some title");
```

Comment: Note that if you have the wrong character size you don't need to explicitly convert the string, you can just explicitly call the appropriate version of the function.  In this case, you could call SetConsoleTitleA (for an ANSI string) or SetConsoleTitleW (for a Unicode string).

Comment: *Technically*, you should be using `UNICODE` and `TEXT()` rather than `_UNICODE` and `_T()`. The former are Win32 macros and `SetConsoleTitle()` is a Win32 function. The latter are C runtime macros and should only be used with C runtime functions. *In practice*, `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` are usually defined together, and so `TCHAR`/`_TCHAR` and `TEXT()`/`_T()` are interchangeable. But I find it best to use the correct macros for whichever library they are being used with. On a side note, your typedefs can be simplified to just `typedef std::basic_string<_TCHAR> tstring;`, no `#ifdef` needed.

Answer (score 4):

```
string str(L"Console title");
SetConsoleTitle(str.c_str());
```

Answer (score 1):

The comment is old but you can do it with the system method...

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    system("title This is a title");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Here is a more universal approach using [ANSI Escape Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#OSC_(Operating_System_Command)_sequences):

```
std::cout << "\033]0;" << "MyTitle" << "\007";
```

On Windows you might have to set the console mode to `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING` (See [SetConsoleMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode)).