# Passing an std::string in SetConsoleTitle() function

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there anyway of converting that string so I can pass the `std::string sTitleName` as a variable in the `SetConsoleTitle()` function? I've tried other forums but they don't seem to provide an answer. Is there anyway of doing it? If not a string, any type of variable that I can use so I can pass a variable name into it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::string sTitleName;
    SetConsoleTitle(TEXT(sName));
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/13219228/8192043

Comment: `SetConsoleTitleA(sName.c_str());`